# Stop MS Teams Tab app from reloading every time I navigate away

Tags: microsoft-teams

I recently have created and deployed an app to work within microsoft teams. It is a tab app, and whenever I click away from the app (maybe i click the chat or calendar buttons on the left nav bar) it will auto close the app and force it to reload every time, meaning I lose all progress. Is there a way to make the app state persist even when I click into another utility in teams?

for example, if I "pop-out" the tab app then the state persists until I close that pop-out. Which is exactly the behavior I want.

Can I get that behavior without needing to click pop-out every time?

Comment: The Microsoft Teams JavaScript client library (TeamsJS) provides support for navigation within a tab. 
Reference doc-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/tab-navigation